# GetWebPart vs. GetWebPart2

Tags: web-services, web-part

I'd like to understand the difference between those Web services:
- GetWebPart vs. GetWebPart2
- GetWebPartProperties vs. GetWebPartProperties2
- SaveWebPart vs. SaveWebPart2

I did a test to compare GetWebPart and GetWebPart2, and they seem to return the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As in my answer to your other post, the docs are horrible. I think that they do return roughly the same thing, but I never found any documentation on what the differences might be between the methods either. The main reason I stopped wrapping this Web Service in SPServices was that it was impossible to figure out how to use it!